# What should I study to learn academic English that is used for mathematics?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for material that can be used to teach non-English speakers academic English for mathematics. I meant it might be some basic vocabulary. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What level of mathematics (school? undergraduate? postgraduate?)  What level of English do the learners already have (you could use the A,B, C categories, for example) Is the main concern for them to understand papers/textbooks written in English, or to write their own papers in English.